# How to change starting from price on WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am wanting to change the from and too price of products within my WooCommerce shop. Instead of displaying "$199.00-$389.00" I want it to read "Staring from $199.00".

I know this cannot be achieved within the settings of WooCommerce. I've had a go at changing the code within mytheme/woocommerce/single-product/price.php which looks like this: 
`

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
global $post, $product;
?>
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
    <meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>" />
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency(); ?>" />
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/<?php echo $product->is_in_stock() ? 'InStock' : 'OutOfStock'; ?>" />
</div>
```

`
[image: Screen shot of problem are]

Comment: If you can access code try explode

Comment: In order to be constructive, it would help if you can post a snippet of something you've tried or be a little more specific about the challenge in relation to the code at hand.

Answer (score 0):

**Untested Code**

Instead of using `get_price_html` use `get_variation_regular_price( 'min' )`

just in case you have sales:

```
$product_on_sale  =  $product->is_on_sale( );

if( $product_on_sale ) {
    $product_price_min  =  $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true );
}
else {
    $product_price_min  =  $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true );
}

echo 'Starting from ' . $product_price_min;
```

Comment: Hi Dez, thank you for your answer. Sorry to seem dumb but do I place 2nd chunk of code you provided within the themes functions.php?

Comment: nope. Put it in the template file you referenced in your question. Everything except the `echo` line can go up where the `global $post, $product;` line is. put the `echo` statement where the current `echo $product->get_price_html()` is currently at.